# CPU Spikes with Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode7, instruments

I am currently working on a game using Sprite Kit in Xcode 7 and I have noticed that as I progress through the game I am getting some fluctuating CPU Spikes.

Each Level in my game is a SKView which is loaded on a single View Controller.

As I play each level and load the next I can see that the max CPU reading in Xcode is slowly climbing until it exceeds 100%, then the game starts to lose frames. Rather than expecting an answer on the culprit outright I am more interested to know what kinds of things put ongoing pressure on the CPU? I have also noticed that even if I dismiss the View Controller that houses the SKView and return to the main menu that the CPU usage still remains high but stops growing upwards.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: creating new sprites without removing them from the scene.  creating lots of sprites during runtime.. like shooting bullets for example